# apt update: "Malformed entry 1 in list file"

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using command sudo apt-get update and this error is coming. How to solve this issue?

```
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and ros melodic.

ros-latest.list content:-

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu  main
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311593/apt-update:-%22malformed-entry-1-in-list-file%22/) by [Keshav](https://answers.ros.org/users/39216/keshav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-12-27

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-12-28**:
What is your question? I don't see any question, just an error or warning without any context. Please see the [support page](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29) for how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (Component)
> ```

```
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Something probably went wrong during initial setup of the ROS package repository sources. Most likely [this section](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list) of the tutorial.

Can you show us the contents of `ros-latest.list`? Use the following command:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

and copy-paste the text from the terminal into your original question text. Use the *edit* button/link for that.

---

Edit:

> ros-latest.list content:-

> ```
> deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu  main
> ```

I have the impression that this is missing the Ubuntu code name for the release, which in your case probably should be `bionic` (provided you are actually running Ubuntu Bionic (ie: `18.04`).

To make sure: what is the output of:

```
lsb_release -sc
```

If that returns an error, or tells you the command `lsb_release` can't be found, then that is most likely what went wrong. If the command can't be found, install it using `sudo apt install lsb-release`.

---

Edit 2:

> it is showing output :- bionic

Then something must have gone wrong while executing this line from [this section](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list) of the tutorial:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Can you run this again and check carefully whether any warnings and/or errors are printed?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Keshav](https://answers.ros.org/users/39216/keshav/) on 2018-12-28**:
uploaded it.

**Comment by [Keshav](https://answers.ros.org/users/39216/keshav/) on 2018-12-28**:
it is showing output :-
bionic

**Comment by [Keshav](https://answers.ros.org/users/39216/keshav/) on 2018-12-28**:
no errors or warnings

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-28**:
Then what is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`?

**Comment by [Keshav](https://answers.ros.org/users/39216/keshav/) on 2018-12-28**:
yes, now bionic was mentioned there in that. I ran the command It's working.
Thanks for helping me out.

**Comment by [j.clownz](https://answers.ros.org/users/45405/j.clownz/) on 2019-09-05**:
this helped, thanks